# Convert tokens into selection ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, selection, rangy

How would I convert a set of token ranges inside a jQuery selection, to a set of [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) ranges?

For example I have this:

```
<div class="test-input">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
        convallis dui id erat pellentesque et rhoncus nunc semper. Suspendisse
        malesuada {hendrerit velit nec }tristique. Aliq{uam gravida mauris at
        ligula venenatis rhoncus. Suspendisse inter}dum, nisi nec consectetur
        pulvinar, lorem augue ornare felis, vel lacinia erat nibh in ve{lit.
    </p>
    <p>
        Hendr}erit, felis ac fringilla lobortis, massa ligula aliquet justo, sit
        amet tincidunt enim quam {sollicitudin} nisi. Maecenas ipsum augue,
        commodo sit amet aliquet ut, laoreet ut nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum
        primis in {fauc}ibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
        Pellentesque tincidunt eros quis tellus laoreet ac dignissim turpis
        luctus. Integer nunc est, {pulvinar ac tempor ac, pretium ut odio.
    </p>
    <p>
        Pellentesque in arcu sit amet} odio scelerisque tincidunt. Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi
        tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    </p>
</div>
```

And I want to convert the text between `{` and `}` into ranges (and remove the tokens).

I tried using this:

```
function tokensToRanges(element) {
    element = $(element);
    var node = element.get(0);
    var ranges = [];
    do {
        var text = $(node).text(),
            start = text.indexOf('{'),
            end = text.indexOf('}') - 1,
            input = null;
        input = node.innerHTML.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
        element.html(input);
        var range = rangy.createRange();
        range.selectCharacters(node, start, end);
        ranges.push(range);
    } while ($(node).text().indexOf('{') != -1);
    return ranges;
}
```

But it the ranges are not correct. I think the `selectCharacters` method ignores whitespace.

Also I would prefer not to use the [`TextRangeModule`](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule) if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectCharacters()` does not ignore all white space but it does ignore collapsed white space. For example, if a text node contains three consecutive space characters, only the first contributes to the character count. I may add an option to that method to switch that behaviour off.

In answer to your question, Rangy's test suite has a function that does something a bit like what you want, so I've adapted it below. Start and end range markers may appear in different nodes.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/DdeFr/

Code:

```
function RangeInfo() {}

RangeInfo.prototype = {
    setStart: function(node, offset) {
        this.sc = node;
        this.so = offset;
    },
    setEnd: function(node, offset) {
        this.ec = node;
        this.eo = offset;
    },
    toRange: function() {
        var range = rangy.createRange();
        range.setStart(this.sc, this.so);
        range.setEnd(this.ec, this.eo);
        return range;
    }
};

function getTextNodesIn(node) {
    var textNodes = [];
    function getTextNodes(node) {
        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            textNodes.push(node);
        } else {
            for (var i = 0, l = node.childNodes.length; i < l; i++) {
                getTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    getTextNodes(node);
    return textNodes;
}

function tokensToRanges(el) {
    var rangeInfos = [];
    var currentRangeInfo;
    var textNodes = getTextNodesIn(el);

    $.each(textNodes, function() {
        var searchStartIndex = 0;
        var searchIndex;
        while ( (searchIndex = this.data.indexOf(currentRangeInfo ? "}" : "{", searchStartIndex)) != -1 ) {
            // Remove the marker. Doing this breaks existing ranges
            // in this node, which is why we use RangeInfo objects
            // instead of ranges
            this.data = this.data.slice(0, searchIndex) + this.data.slice(searchIndex + 1);
            if (currentRangeInfo) {
                currentRangeInfo.setEnd(this, searchIndex);
                rangeInfos.push(currentRangeInfo);
                currentRangeInfo = null;
            } else {
                currentRangeInfo = new RangeInfo();
                currentRangeInfo.setStart(this, searchIndex);
            }
            searchStartIndex = searchIndex;
        }
    });

    // Convert RangeInfos into ranges
    var ranges = [];
    $.each(rangeInfos, function() {
        ranges.push(this.toRange());
    });

    return ranges;
}

var ranges = tokensToRanges(document.body);
var applier = rangy.createCssClassApplier("highlight");
applier.applyToRanges(ranges);
```

Comment: I found an edge case that has me stumped: http://jsfiddle.net/DdeFr/1/ Any ideas?

Comment: @Petah: Ah yes. I never use jQuery so that was unusual for me, and now it's bitten me. Here's my update: http://jsfiddle.net/DdeFr/3/